# How to solved flutter firebase_analytics dependency error?

Tags: android, flutter

```
 The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
 Because chat_applicaion depends on firebase_analytics >=0.0.2 <0.3.0 which requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.pub get failed (1)
```

I have change flutter SDK but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try updating your `firebase_analytics` version on `pubspec.yaml` or whatever firebase plugin you have in this file. It seems like our chat application uses an older version of the plugin.